# Installing Poppler for PDF text extraction

Tags: python, pdftotext, poppler

I am trying to follow this blog in trying to extract text from an invoice pdf file. My text extraction requires extraction specific fields of the invoice.

https://kaijento.github.io/2017/03/27/pdf-scraping-gwinnetttaxcommissioner.publicaccessnow.com/#pdftotext

I have tried pdfminer, textract but they all extract the text as jumbled and its difficult to extract text after that.

I came across Poppler package download below:

https://poppler.freedesktop.org/releases.html

Looks like its a .tar file. And not a python package.

Am not sure how to use this .tar file to extract the package and use it in Python.

Any suggestions how I install this on my mac and then use it programatically in python to run a bunch of pdf files through this to extract data.

Answer (score 3):

Use `subprocess` to call the `pdftotext` program from the xpdf tools. You can find ms-windows versions of those tools at https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html. Get the "Xpdf command line tools".

I use it like this (python 3.7):

```
import subprocess as sp

def pdftotext(path):
    """
    Generate a text rendering of a PDF file in the form of a list of lines.
    """
    args = ['pdftotext', '-layout', path, '-']
    cp = sp.run(
      args, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.DEVNULL,
      check=True, text=True
    )
    return cp.stdout
```

Comment: any idea how to get that installed for mac OS or linux? Do u think the same can be done via Poppler? Thnx

Comment: @Baktaawar On Linux and macOS, install the `poppler-utils` package. [Available](https://pkgs.org/download/poppler-utils) on Linux and *BSD.

Comment: which one of those? And I know Mac OS is linux based, but will the linux one work on mac? I tried doing xpdfreader installation from here 

https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html

Downloaded the mac one and did tar xvzj 

I got it unzippped. But when I run 

./configure it says No such directory

Comment: any idea how can we install this xpdreader on mac? it doesnt seem to hv a ./configure file

Comment: Not every piece of software uses autoconf. It could be using another build system like `cmake`, `waf` or about a dozen others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try poppler for python here: https://pypi.org/project/python-poppler-qt5/

Comment: This is new. Didn't know that. Thanks for sending. I don't see functions to extract text using this.Do u knw how can we use the above .tar file to extract some stuff?

Comment: I have installed this one from conda. Do u think same stuff?

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/poppler

Comment: conda or pip must work. Alternatively, if you want to install from source code, extract files from .tar file and run: `python setup.py install`

Comment: I installed from this https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/poppler 

Did conda install poppler. 

See it in conda env. But when I do import poppler it says no module. Is that the name?

Comment: check the code for reference here: https://github.com/jalan/pdftotext

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to Install poppler in Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install libpoppler-cpp-dev

pip install --use-pep517 .
```